# Shortcut: CSS into page

Tags: html

I found this CSS file on the internet, however, I like using the old way of putting all code in one page without using css files but I faild here.

```
 @font-face
 {
 font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
 src:url(/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format("woff2")
 }
 
 .glyphicon{
 font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
 font-weight:400;
 }

.glyphicon-triangle-top:before{content:"\e253"}
```

And whenever I use `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>` it shows the symbol

I tried to put it on my page as follows but it didn't work. What is wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
     .header.expand .sign:after{
        font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
        src:url(/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format("woff2");
        content:"\e253";     
     }
         </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="header expand">
<td><span class="sign"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2`?

Comment: Yes Justinas I do

Answer (score 0):

I just sort it out. Thank for all who tired to help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face{
                font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
                src:url(/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format("woff2")
        }

        .header .sign:after{
                font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
                font-weight:400;
                content:"\e253";
                display:inline-block      
        }
         </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="header expand">
<td><span class="sign"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```